# Prove it is a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

This question seriously bothering me, because there is one part I really don`t know how even to start thinking of it:

Define

1. $$f(x)=e^{1/x} \text{ for } x\in R-\{0\}$$
2. $$\lt \lambda,\phi\gt= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \phi^{(k)} \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^k$$

show that this defines $\lambda$, and $f(x)$ as a distribution on $R-\{0\}$ and prove that $\lambda$ is not of finite order. Show that there does not exist any distribution $g \in D'(R)$ such that $g=f$ on $R-\{0\}$

I`m totally confused with the part there is no $g$ distribution and do not know how to start solving it.

Thanks

Comment: Why is $\lambda$ well defined?

Comment: $\phi$ is finitely differentiable so the derivatives of all orders exists.

Comment: It is a series ${}{}{}$

Comment: It is important to note that distributions are not defined pointwise unlike functions. So if you have function f defined on R-{0}, obviously there is function g on R whose restriction gives you f (just put g(0)=0). This is not the case with distributions as distributions can only be defined on open sets. So the open sets R-{0} and R are totally different open sets and cannot be compared so easily

Comment: For 1. Assume such a distribution g exists and hence this distribution will have finite order say k in the open interval (-1,1). Then consider the test function $x^{(k+1)}*\phi(x)$ where $\phi(x)$ is a bump function on (-1,1). Integrating g against this test function will give you the value infinity a contradiction

Comment: For 2. Same method. assume it is a finite order distribution around -1/2, construct test function which is a polynomial around -1/2 with the properties that its first k+1 derivatives vanish at -1/2 but k+2 derivative does not. This gives contradiction

Comment: one more thing. how can I prove $e^{(1/x)}$ defines a distribution since it has $1/x$ ?

Comment: Do you know how a distribution on $R\setminus\{0\}$ is defined?

Comment: still I`m not sure how to do it here.

Comment: Definition(!): A locally integrable function $f\in L^1_\text{loc}(\Omega)$ defines a distribution on $\Omega$ by $f(\varphi)=\int_\Omega f\varphi$ for all $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. For $\Omega=R\setminus\{0\}$ you know what for $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ ?

Comment: yup, I know how to do it now!